# Add custom HTML to WP Post based on custom field using plugin

Tags: wordpress

The wordpress plugin I'm developing needs to be able to display some custom HTML in posts. I know that this is possible with shortcodes, but unfortunately I'm limited to using 'custom fields'. In order to deside which HTML should be added, the authors set a custom field (using a post-meta-box in the backend created by the plugin).

But I can't find any documention on how to achieve this. It's easy if you edit the wordpress theme, but this plugin should work across different themes.

Anyone able to guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I think I found out which direction I should take this... use http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content and then check the meta data for the post.

Comment: Do you need help in displaying `meta boxes` or do you want help in adding and using `custom fields` in a theme?

Comment: Adding the meta boxes was easy :-). But now I'm trying to let my plugin display HTML in posts based on the custom fields created by the meta box. I'm on the right track, don't need help anymore. Will update post as soon as I got the full solution right.